# React Native log-android strange crash output

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, adb, android-logcat

Whenever I run react-native log-android I get this:

```
Starting the logger (/Users/axel/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb logcat *:S ReactNative:V ReactNativeJS:V)...
--------- beginning of crash
--------- beginning of system
--------- beginning of main
```

Why does it say beginning of crash? My app isn't crashing.

Answer (score 1):

`crash`, `system` and `main` are just the names of different log buffers and `--------- beginning of crash` line just marks the beginning of that section in the log. It is immediately followed by `--------- beginning of system` (i.e. the header of the next section) which means that the `crash` section is empty.

Comment: Do you have a sauce?

Comment: Are you short on condiments?

Comment: source* is what I meant